# Index content of YOOtheme text modules

Tags: joomla-3.x, search, smartsearch, zoo

I activated the Zoo search plugin as described at https://yootheme.com/support/zoo/search-plugin and yet what inside YOOtheme text modules (created using the YOOtheme builder) isn't indexed for the search (not even when I start the indexing process manually). Am I possibly missing something? What has to be configured so this content is indexed?

Indexing traditional Joomla articles and ZOO-powered blog posts works though.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provide says it will index '... Items and Categories of Zoo' so it is likely the text you are including in the Zoo text module is not searched. An email to YOO might confirm this.

Plugins to Joomla Search normally define extra database tables, in this case Zoo Items and Categories, to be including in searching and indexing. How or where Zoo stores the information in your text module would determine whether it is indexed.

Terry

Comment: It is stored in the `prefix_modules` database table, that much I know… but yes, e-mail is probably a good idea.

Comment: If it is just using the standard Joomla module then it is unlikely to be searched/indexed. If a module was indexed how would it know what to display if there was a match.

Comment: The page where the module is on?

Comment: A module can be assigned to one or more or no pages at all so if the search plugin indexed the text it found in the #__modules table and found a match for text in a module that appears alongside 30 different articles/items across 10 different  menus and was display it in a search results and the end user clicks on it, which menu/article would be displayed? Joomla Search isn't like Google that records which pages a keyword appears on on.

Comment: Joomla scans a database table to index a keyword with an ID of an article or item of a component so when it  is selected from a search results list, the default processing for the article/item ID takes over and displays the correct page, menu, moduels etc.